# Baked textures looking like this, any ideas? New to Blender

Tags: texture-baking

I'll try keep it brief:

I've had no issues baking textures when I've got just one renderdoc import, however Im having issues now that I'm getting to more complex geometry.

In the linked image ( https://i.redd.it/rm4bvyi0z5k51.png ) I've got a combination of renderdoc (rdc) files which I have stitched together using a Blender addon.

The process I followed to obtain a single .png texture was as follows - (THIS PROCESS WORKS):

1. Import the .rdc
2. Ctrl J to join the original mesh together
3. Duplicate the mesh

Run the following code on the duplicate to remove the textures:

```
import bpy
C = bpy.context
for i in range(0,len(C.object.material_slots)):
    C.object.active_material_index = 1
    bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove()
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'SELECT')
    bpy.ops.object.material_slot_assign()
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
```

4 Go into the shader editor and shift + a to add an 'image texture'. Leave it disconnected from the 'principled BSDF'

5. Select the original which still has textures and use 'cycles' render engine and bake type 'diffuse' to bake.

Again, the above process WORKS.

More complex process I'm having issues with:

I wanted to step it up a notch so I used a blender addon to stitch together a bunch of rdc files.

1. Each renderdoc file is imported to its own 'collection'
2. Select all of the collections and run the following code to merge everything to one object:

```
    import bpy
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    mesh = [m for m in bpy.context.scene.objects if m.type == 'MESH']
    for obj in mesh: obj.select_set(state=True)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    bpy.ops.object.join()
```

3. Duplicate the mesh

Run the following code on the duplicate to remove the textures:

```
import bpy
C = bpy.context
for i in range(0,len(C.object.material_slots)):
    C.object.active_material_index = 1
    bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove()
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'SELECT')
    bpy.ops.object.material_slot_assign()
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
```

5. With the duplicate selected, go into the shader editor and create a new principled BSFD. shift + a to add an 'image texture'. Leave it disconnected from the 'principled BSDF'
6. Select the original which still has textures and use 'cycles' render engine and bake type 'diffuse' to bake.

Unfortunately, after baking I'm getting these obviously incorrect textures. The only thing I'm doing differently is running the code to merge all of the objects into one, I'm guessing when this happens over multiple collections it is somehow screwing with the materials (even though the merged object looks perfectly fine in blender once its all one object).

Can anyone advise on what is potentially going wrong here. I'm very new to blender so only ask that any responses please keep them detailed enough for a noob to understand. Thanks!

Comment: Can you clean up you post's python? I was going to reformat it for you, but the white-space is corrupted. Try starting and ending each code block with three back tics ```

Comment: @christopher-bennett marked it as code, but I'm still not clear what is going on with the first piece of code.

Comment: The first piece of code is just a quick way to remove all materials from a particular object. When there are hundreds of materials for one object this saves you from deleting them individually. Happy to answer as many questions as I need to to get this sorted. Appreciate the help